# How to limit input value to 2 digit numbers, but also allowing the use of 3 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number of input boxes on a html page. I want to restrict the user to input letters and large numbers. I know how to only accept a certain string length but this will not do. The user must be able to use decimals in their numbers.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" maxlength = "2">
<button id="enter_button">Enter</button>
```

Javascript

```
$("#enter_button").click(function(){
    var Input = $("#userInput").val();
    if(!isNaN(Input)){
        //Carry out code
    }else{
        $("#userInput").val("");
        alert("You must enter a number");
    };
});
```

This is an example of what my code is currently at. As you can see this just performs a simple validation check to see if the input is a number or not. I have set the maxlength to 2 for the input field but by doing so this stops the user from entering decimals after 2 digits.
I want the user to be able to submit for example, 2.678 or 87.786.
If the only way is to use validation such as what I have done here then I'll have to live with doing that.

P.S. The characters I am looking to restrict are whitespaces, letters and special characters e.g. Hello, !%^&. And by large numbers I mean anything above 100. min= 0.000, max= 99.999.

Comment: Have a look at Regex

Comment: Please provide what you've tried already, as well as examples of some valid and invalid data.

Comment: I've just got as for as setting the inputs maxlength = "2". I have validation checks to see if the value is a string or a number but I just want to restrict the user being able to type strings and/or large numbers. Plus I want to avoid using more libraries

Comment: I think what you need is to preform validation of the input value after it's entered. You cant really restrict input to large numbers while it's being input (meaning numbers greater than 9). restricting input to only numbers and letters is possible though.

Comment: @JimiiBee - I understand your basic point, but we need to know more about the validations . . . do "strings" include **any** characters?  Spaces? Just letters?  What are "large numbers"?  Is there a maximum number of decimal places?  Can there be comma seperators for thousands/millions/etc.?

Comment: I would recommend updating your question displaying relevant source code, this will save us having to guess / assume what you have working so far. If you want this problem fixing then display the relevant source code to help us help you. If we have nothing to debug then we don't have the answers for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should explain what you mean by "strings", but this regex accepts up to 2 digit numbers with with up to 3 decimal places.

However, a decimal point followed by nothing is not accepted. E.g "12." returns false

```
var regex = /^\d{0,2}\.\d{1,3}$|^\d{0,2}$/
var match = regex.test("11.334"); //boolean
```

Comment: Sorry didn't mean "strings". I meant letters